# Converting Python 2.7 to Python 3 with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a working application using Python 2.7 and Tkinter that uses these constructs:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog

class Window(Frame):                  
    #...
    #     other functional code
    #...

    def ChangeCWD(self):       #CWD is current working directory
        root = Tkinter.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        directory = tkFileDialog.askdirectory( ... )

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

It has labels, buttons, canvas, multiple frames and file dialogue boxes and it all works nicely.
I have begun updating the code to work on Python 3.5 and, so far all functions seem to work except for the file dialog. This is where I have got to so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog

class Window(Frame):                  
    #...
    #     other functional code
    #...

    def ChangeCWD(self):       #CWD is current working directory
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        directory = filedialog.askdirectory( ... )

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

However this code produces the error

> "NameError: name 'filedialog' is not defined"

when the filedialog.askdirectory() statement is reached.  Could anyone provide any help to understand what I should do to correct the situation please?

As an aside, please be gentle with me! I've always been rather mystified by the various ways of invoking import statements and how to use "tk." or "root." before some function calls. There are simply too many conflicting explanations out on the web that I can't get a clear picture.

Comment: You didn't import any such thing as `filedialog`, so that can't possibly work.  You did import `tkinter.filedialog`, so try that instead (I don't have a Python 3 installation handy to check if that's right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `import tkinter.filedialog`, which imports `tkinter.filedialog` with the namespace `tkinter.filedialog`, then you try to use `filedialog` in your code.

Pick one of these two:

- change your call to `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory( ... )`
- change your import to `import filedialog from tkinter`, which will import `tkinter.filedialog` with the namespace `filedialog`.

Note: `from tkinter import *` might seem like it should import `filedialog`, but that `*` does not import submodules unless the package has explicitly specified that they should.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation has helped a lot. To test my understanding, am I right that a) "from tkinter import *" will import all classes, functions, static variables etc but not submodules and b) tkinter.filedialog is a sub module?

Comment: Is there an easy reference source that clarifies which features of tkinter are actually submodules? python.org is so vast its overwhelming.

Comment: Try https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules and look for the list following the line "Other modules that provide Tk support include".  That seems to list most of them.  There does not appear to be further documentation for most of them there though.